# How to display data in three columns

Tags: javascript, html

I am loading all my data into a table using AJAX. Currently, all the data is being displayed as separate rows, but when handling 100 rows, I want it to display as 3 columns. Example: If there's 30 data, first 10 in one column, next 10 in another column, an so on.

Below is my current code. Please advice how to proceed:

```
$('form').on('submit', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: "{{ url('codes1/')}}",
    data: $('form').serialize(),
    success: function (data) {

      if (data) {
        if(data == "error"){
          alert("Please enter number between 1 - 200");
        }

        var json_obj = $.parseJSON(data);

        //parse JSON
        var output = "<tr class='ddd'>";

        for (var i in json_obj) {

          var code = json_obj[i].code;
          var code_no = json_obj[i].code_no;

          output += "<td style='border: none!important'></td>" +
                    "<td style='border: none!important'>" + code_no + "</td>" +
                    "<td style='border: none!important'><span style='float: left' '>" + code + "</span></td>";

          output += "</tr>";
        }

        $('#span2').html(output);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Please add more information about the CSS library you are using, and this pure Javascript, so, I am removing Laravel from tags.

Comment: The example is a bit confusing and doesn't match the code (you are displaying everything in 3 columns always). Also the code has a bug: you are closing the `</tr>` many times, but you are opening it only once.